# Sum of segments that satisfy condition in list

Tags: python, list

How do I create a new list containing sum of segments where the True elements within the main_list consecutively repeat for at least 3 times or more (`min_segment=3`)?

```
> main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]  
> min_segment=3
```

The expected answer should be:

```
> true_sum = [5, 3]
> #repeating segment at index 4 and contains 5 consecutive True elements, and next repeating segment at index 11 containing 3 True elements. Both segments are greater or equal to `min_segment` so are included in the `true_sum` list. 
> #the first repeating True segment starts at index 0 but contains 2 elements from main_list which is less than the `min_segment`, so is excluded from the `true_sum` list.
```

**I need a simple code that does not require the use of numpy or groupby.**

So far, my code shows the sum for all repeating True segments and does not account for the condition to only include the sum of segments with **at least 3 or more** True elements (`min_segment=3`).

```
> count = 0
> true_sum = []
> for v in main_list:
    if v:
        count += 1
    elif count:
        true_sum.append(count)
        count = 0
> if count:
        true_sum.append(count)
```

This gives an incorrect list of where the 2 should have been excluded:

```
> true_sum = [2,5,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer greatly inspired by Paul's code, I just removed the function definition and tweaked it to make it work in a couple of specific cases:

```
min_segment = 3

lengths = []
length = 0
prev_value = False

for value in main_list:

    if value:
        length += 1

    elif prev_value and not value:
        if length > min_segment:
            lengths.append(length)
        length = 0

    prev_value = value

if length >= min_segment:
    lengths.append(length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly don't want a `groupby` solution, here's a simple generator. Not a huge fan of this solution, however, because I'm repeating myself in a couple places. Open to suggestions for improvement:

```
def segment_sums(segments, min_segments=3):

    prev_segment = None
    curr_sum = 1

    for segment in segments:
        if segment == prev_segment:
            curr_sum += 1
        else:
            if curr_sum >= min_segments:
                yield curr_sum
            prev_segment = segment
            curr_sum = 1
    if curr_sum >= min_segments:
        yield curr_sum

segments = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
print(list(segment_sums(segments)))
```

Comment: Is there a more general code to this that does not involve defining a new function? The example I gave of my code is a simplified version of a code that I already defined under another function which I excluded from this question because I thought it might overcomplicate things, if that makes sense.

Comment: This doesn't work because it also counts sequences of 3 or more `False` values

Comment: @Avandale Oops, didn't read the prompt thoroughly.